# TextView tapping is not working on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, ios14

I have two question about `textView` tapping detection,
first is, I know it's working well with web site urls, but if the url is the `mailto` url, it will open the mail app?

the second and my biggest problem is, when I use Xcode 11.7 or 12 GM to run the project on iOS 13.5 device simulators, the tap on url is working well, but not `mailto` (it's expected), but when I run the app on iOS 14 devices and simulator, the `textView` detect the links, but tapping is not working at all. Is it the big from iOS 14 or something change on iOS14?

Answer (score 2):

If you call `gestureRecognizers` on UITextField in iOS 14, it'll return you 17 (!) entities, including a few responsible for interaction with detected links:

- UITextInteractionNameLinkTap
- UITextInteractionNameSingleTap
- UITextInteractionNameDoubleTap
- UITextInteractionNameTapAndAHalf

They have cross-dependencies, specifically "single tap" ones are expecting the double-tap to fail.

Indeed, taps on links did not work for me, while a double-tap would open it.

So the workaround is to remove that double-tap gesture so it does not block all the rest:

```swift
if let doubleTap = textView.gestureRecognizers?
    .first(where: { ($0 as? UITapGestureRecognizer)?.numberOfTapsRequired == 2 }) {
    textView.removeGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}
```

Comment: all those gesture you listed, such as "UITextInteractionNameLinkTap", are not appearing for me when i print all the textView's gesture recognizers. i'm seeing a total of 13 gestures, so i'm missing those two. why might those be gone for me?